# Memoryleak on navigation of viewcontroller in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have done navigation one viewcontroller to another, But when I done navigation multiple times my application shows memory leak, I run application with NSZombie detection ,that shows "Insufficient task_for_pid privileges (LeakAgent)". It is ARC enabled(xcode 4.2, iOS5) Please help.......

My code is here:

```
self.locationMapDetail = [[LocationMapDetail alloc] init];  //14.3% Leak
self.locationMapDetail.objItem = [self.parsedItems objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]; //5.7% Leak       
[self.navigationController pushViewController:locationMapDetail animated:YES]; //80.3% Leak
self.locationMapDetail = nil;
self.locationMapDetail.objItem = nil;
```

Comment: the leak is not necessary to be in one of these lines .. maybe the internal functions cause the leak .. check the "LocationMapDetail" `viewDidLoad` and other methods will be fired when you show this viewController.

Comment: Instruments doesn't telle you the line where the leak is, but the line where the leak appears: so the leak can be in another methods or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must release the objects before making it nil.Something like

```
[self.locationMapDetail release];
self.locationMapDetail = nil;
```

You should do it for all the objects that you allocate , if you are not using ARC.

In case of strong pointers even if you release the object you might not release it efficiently or it may be only virtually released as a strong pointer can be released only if all the references of the strong pointer has been released.It happens because sometimes the target may have strong pointer reference back to the declared variable.

Also Please mention the method you are using to create your variables..(viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear).It is advisable to create it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: This is wrong for two reasons: 1. The question states that ARC is enabled, so no need for `release`. 2. Under manual reference counting, setting a property to nil actually will release the value; no need for a separate `release`.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong, setting to nil will release the object... and ARC is enabled too, so no need of releases

Comment: @Marco..When i gave the answer ARC was not mentioned ..moreover in certain cases u KNow when exactly to release the resources or u don't want the references ..you can do it nil in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, It took me almost 2 days to resolve the issue. Finally got the solution.
Make sure that your profile scheme is in DEBUG mode instead of RELEASE. This will solve the issue.